# Android Sherlock Actionbar onOptionsItemSelected is not called

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

> I m using Sherlock Actionbar to show share option in Action Bar of my application.
>   The Share option works fine.
>
> I want to get the option which user selects from Share option, so that I can share
>   different text for facebook, messages, mail etc.
>
> For this I am using **onOptionsItemSelected** function but this function
>   is never called.
>
> Please help me to fix this or is there any workaround
>   to achieve this. Thanks..

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

        Intent intent = getDefaultShareIntent();

        if(intent!=null)
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }    

    /** Returns a share intent */
    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){     

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Sample Content !!!");
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
        System.out.println("Testing...................");
        return false;    
    }

}
```

**Items.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="@string/share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"        
    />    
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For this I am using onOptionsItemSelected function but this function is never called.

It is not supposed to be called. It is not called for any action provider.

> I want to get the option which user selects from Share option, so that I can share different text for facebook, messages, mail etc.

That is not directly supported by `ShareActionProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Can I get any help to achieve this?

Comment: @Rizvi: Write your own action provider, perhaps forking the code of the action provider that you are using and making changes to it.